How to implement topic level authentication for kafka using SASL-PLAIN for windows using python?
I have implemented broker level authentication using SASL-PLAIN, now i want to add topic level authorization using ACLs. Im not able to do that
I am running zookeeper and broker on local with default ports.
Please help.
My server.properties are:
    # Enable SASL/PLAIN authentication
    listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    # SASL/PLAIN settings
    security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
    # Specify the JAAS configuration file
       listener.name.sasl_plaintext.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModu   le required user_admin="admin-password";
    allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
    super.users=User:admin
    authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer


zookeeper.properties are unchanged
i have also added a kafka_server_jaas.conf file:
    KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-password"
    user_admin="admin-password"
    user_readAlice="alice-password"
    user_writeBob="bob-password";
    };

on restarting the broker it shows the following error:
    ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:426)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:415)
    at kafka.security.authorizer.AuthorizerUtils$.createAuthorizer(AuthorizerUtils.scala:31)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.createNewAuthorizer(KafkaConfig.scala:1840)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:531)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:112)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2024-07-24 16:13:37,285] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)


Are you following specific documentation? The class name should be kafka.security.authorization.SimpleAclAuthorizer
